# iOS people picker change buttons color

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uicolor

I'm trying to change the ABPeoplePicker (contact list) navigation items color, because buttons in my app are white and so I can't see them on this window. I tried a lot of things like this :

```
peoplePicker.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

... or that :

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

but there is no way...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
  ** = [UIColor redColor];
```

Hope this helps

Swift:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Something like that? Please let me know

Comment: Using Swift bro :), not Objective-C

Comment: you tagged both, that's why I gave you an obj-c answer

Comment: What does ** means ? I can't found it on the net.